# Android ListView: How to fill ListView with empty values to fit the screen

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, rows

i have a problem with ListView. If i add only 3 objects to Adapter (on the screen i can fit for example 8) i get empty space under the List. I want to put another rows in it with backround like items above but without text. I change row background in Adapter getView method. Ofcourse sometimes i have more items to show than screen can fit and in this case everything looks great amd works ok with scroll.

**Now it looks like:**

[img1 http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/194/k4zq.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/194/k4zq.png)

**Should be:**

[img2 http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/837/qr2y.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/837/qr2y.png)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: If the black area is the problem, i think you simply set your items' background to parent view's background and make your items' background transparent. Otherwise that would be iOS Table like @PareshMayani said

Comment: You have to the extend the listview like it is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27416331/3808178). I tested it and  it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in the adapter a minimum amount of items in the list. The best place would be the getCount()-Method. For your example the minimum amount would be 8. In your getView you have to handle Nullpointers, so you place empty views with only the background in there. Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Yes it's good idea but i don't know how many rows will be available (my application will be used on hdpi, mdpi and xhdpi, 8 was only an example ). It would be nice do something like this in getCount(): return listViewHeight / rowHeight but in adapter there is no such properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your layout.. use weightsum and layoutweight in xml for proper adjustment of items in screen.

Comment: I tried set weightSum and layout_weight, it's not working. The same situation when i set "fill_parent".

Answer (score 0):

Best resolution would be as I comment before, do something like that: in `getCount()`: return listViewHeight / rowHeight but in adapter there is no such properties. I don't know how many rows will be available, my application will be used on hdpi, mdpi and xhdpi resolution, 8 rows was only an example.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to your `ListView`